# How to add an icon to the status bar of a Golang GioUI app?

Tags: go, user-interface

I was able create a window with a **title** and an scpecific **size** using [GioUI](https://gioui.org/). However, I couldn't add an **icon** to my `app.NewWindow`. It looks like `app` has nothing related to that [in the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/gioui.org@v0.0.0-20230421192146-880cd27f59ca/app)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "gioui.org/app"
    "gioui.org/unit"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        // Create a new 800x720 window with a title
        w := app.NewWindow(
            app.Title("MyApp"),
            app.Size(unit.Dp(800), unit.Dp(720)),
        )
        // Calls main routine
        err := routine(w)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
    app.Main()
}
```